# Converting from JS to TS: Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the binding element has no default value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am converting this code from JavaScript to TypeScript:

```js
const RGB_HEX = /^#?(?:([\da-f]{3})[\da-f]?|([\da-f]{6})(?:[\da-f]{2})?)$/i;

const [, short, long] = String(hex).match(RGB_HEX) || [];
```

But it throws errors at line columns 12 and 19:

> TS2525: Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the binding element has no default value.

I can't figure out what TS wants me to do. How can I refactor this code so it does not throw an error? TIA

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gCxADwC54oUBPAbgFgAoUSWBZdLAJQHEAhAfQAkBRABpFMMAJYoA5lWo0mmeAG0ANPDTYkMDCoioJAXXgBeeAGUMYyQApceAJQA6ALZQMYbJfbd+A2-AA+fop65EA) EDIT: tried it with `RGB_HEX: RegExp` but [still no repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gCxADwC54oUBPAbgFgAoUSWBZdLAJQHEAhAfQAkBRABpEWIAOZ88AByrUaTTPADaAGnhpsSGBlURUogLrwAvPADKGGAEsUogBS48ASgB0AWygYw2W+278BjvAAPkFK+uRAA)

Comment: I'm unable to get error either, what version of TS and what are hex & RGB_HEX just in case they have an effect.   All I did was substitute hex for a string, and 'RGB_HEX` for some regEx and it didn't complain.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes my IDE does not throw a linter error but when I compile Storybook https://storybook.js.org/ it throws the error.

Comment: Thanks @Keith have added `RGB_HEX`, TS 3.5.3

Comment: Ok, Right.. Tested with 3.5.1, and the error appears,.. I would suggest updating TS..

Comment: The code is a bit problematic because `[]` doesn't have 3 elements to initialise `short` and `long`  with. What happens is left a bit implicit

Comment: @Keith - Genius! Problem solved :) Thanks